# How can I bring a specific commit and work on it : on git

Tags: git

I am a new user of the git.
I have many files.

How can I bring a specific file and work on it,Without deleting other commit?
I tried to use reset --hard  and checkout 
but This deletes all other commit.
What is the correct way?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do?

Comment: Where are you starting from? Did you do a `git init` and `git commit -a` already?

Comment: What does "How can I bring a specific file and work on it,Without deleting other commit?" mean? Also "This deletes all other commit" does not seem possible in the context of Git. Do you mean the working tree no longer has the changes that were there prior to doing a checkout? If so it is working by design and you need to freshen up your understanding on what Git does.

Comment: I want to go back to Old commit without show  files that were added after it.
Sorry I use google  translator

Answer (score 0):

From reading your title and comments afterward, I interpreted this question to mean that you want to go back to an old commit and work off of it, but still have new changes intact for future purposes.

First, commit all of the files you are working on so that you don't lose anything. Then, perform a

```
git log
```

and find the commit hash for the commit you want to go back to. Copy that commit into your clipboard, and then type

```
git branch <insert_new_branch_name_here> <insert_commit_hash_here>
```

Then,

```
git checkout <insert_new_branch_name_here>
```

This should bring you to a new branch whose latest revision is the commit you want to work from.

Your previous changes that were on top of this commit will still be available in the branch you were originally on.